# line in ggplot connects all dots and not only those in group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have molten dataframe and wants to plot all the different variables with a line. However when i do that GGplot connects all lines and the plot is meaningless.

```
df <-data.frame (names =c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),
   time = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
   xvar = c(150,37,38,150,50,50))

ggplot(df,aes(x=time, y=xvar), group = names)+
  geom_line()
```

Can this be fixed, so the plot shows three lines connecting the dots in each variable

Comment: Just put `group = names` inside `aes()`. Sometimes `colour = names` is better. Vote to close as off-topic/simple error or typo.

Answer (score 1):

You put the group outside of the `aes()`. It needs to be inside the `aes()`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=time, y=xvar, group = names)) +
  geom_line()
```